# What are the indecomposable classes on a del-Pezzo surface?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, gromov-witten-theory, enumerative-geometry

Let $X_k$ be $\mathbb{P}^2$ blown up at $k$ points (where $k$ is $0$ to $8$). 
Let $\beta \in H_2(X_k, \mathbb{Z}) $ be a homology class given by 
$$ \beta := n L + m_1 E_1 + \ldots + m_k E_k $$ 
where $L$ is the homology class of a line and $E_i$ are the exceptional 
divisors. My question is as follows:

Which homology classes are $\textit{indecomposable}$? By definition, a homology 
class is indecomposable if:

a) It can be represented by a non constant holomorphic map 
$u:\mathbb{P}^1 \longrightarrow X_k $  and

b) It cannot be written as $\beta = \beta_1 + \ldots \beta_n$ for some $n \geq 2$ 
such that each $\beta_i$ has a non constant holomorphic representative 
(as a map from $\mathbb{P}^1 $ to $X_k$).

My motivation for asking the question is as follows: I am explicitly trying to 
work out what is $N_{\beta}$, the number of rational curves in $X_k$ (through the right number of generic points) that represent the class $\beta$. Kontsevich and Mannin have given a recursive formula for this number in their paper (page 29)

http://www.ihes.fr/~maxim/TEXTS/WithManinCohFT.pdf

In order to actually calculate what is $N_{\beta}$, we need some initial conditions. I think the initial condition is that $N_{\beta} =1$ if $\beta$ is indecomposable.

$\textbf{Added Later:}$ Based on Mark's observation (and one further question I have about Kontsevich Mannin's paper) I have posted a separate question on mathoverflow

[Are genus zero Gromov Witten Invariants on Del-Pezzo surfaces enumerative?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207812/are-genus-zero-gromov-witten-invariants-on-del-pezzo-surfaces-enumerative)

Comment: If $k \geq 2$ the extremal rays on the cone of curves are all the classes of $(-1)$-curves (which are in particular rational), and I guess these classes should be indecomposable.  Any other effective class can be written as a positive $\mathbb Q$-linear combination of these, but maybe not as an integer combination, I suppose.  Do you know any examples of indecomposable classes that aren't just $(-1)$-curves?

Comment: I guess when $k = 8$ you have the class of a nodal cubic through the points.  So there are more than just $(-1)$-curves.  (I think for that class $N_\beta = 12$, though I could be wrong.)

Comment: @Mark: see http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0309111, especially Corollary 3.3.

Comment: Dear Mark, I also know nothing about Gromov-Witten theory, so I won't say anything about that part. I am a little confused about your earlier mention of nodal cubics, though; given 8 general points there won't be a cubic through all of them and with a node at one. Did you mean just that the cubic has a node somewhere? Then I agree such a curve exists, but it has the same class as a smooth cubic through the 8 points. On the other hand, in your last comment you just wrote the class of a smooth cubic, so maybe I am misunderstanding you. In any case, Batyrev--Popov seems to answer OP's question.

Comment: @Artie Yes, I mean a cubic through all of them with a node somewhere -- in that case the class should be represented by a map from $\mathbb P^1 \to X_k$ as needed (I think?).  It's true that the class $3L - \sum E_i$ is represented by smooth cubics, but $N_\beta$ is only counting rational curves in the class, which should come from the singular cubics in the pencil.  Anyway, I suspect I am misunderstanding something and embarrassing myself.

Comment: Dear Mark, of course, I was forgetting that we are talking about maps from $\mathbf P^1$, not just looking at numerical classes. My mistake!

Comment: @Artie PS: Sorry for deleting my earlier comment.  I think you're right that Batyrev-Popov seems to do what the question asks.  I'm a little confused about the anticanonical class for $k=8$, which seems to me to be indecomposable with $N_\beta = 12$, although Kontsevich-Manin suggest that $N_\beta = 1$ on a del Pezzo.  Hopefully the poster can sort us out.

Comment: To the OP: I skimmed the Kontsevich-Manin notes, but I couldn't find the claim that $N_\beta=1$ for an indecomposable class --- where is it written? As Mark observes, there are 12 nodal cubics through 8 general points, which seems in conflict with this claim.

Comment: I'm looking after claim 5.2.3 on page 29 -- "It is expected that all these values are 1"

Comment: @Ritwik There are no such curves if the points are general.  The only way that class can be effective is if all $8$ points are collinear.

Comment: @Mark: I see. I don't know how to reconcile that "expectation" with your observation.

Comment: @Artie and Mark: I think the anticanonical class for k= is decomposable. The class is 3L−E1−…−E8. This can be written as 3(L−E1−…−E8)+2E1+…+2E8. This is a decomposition (there are holomorphic curves of class (L−E1−…−E8) I think).

Comment: @Ritwik: Mark's previous comment (which was in response to what appears to be the identical comment from you, now deleted) remains true.

Comment: @ Mark: As per the definition of indecomposable; I said a class $\beta$ is indecomposable if it can be written as $\beta_1 + \beta_2 + \ldots $ where there are holomorphic representatives for each $\beta_i$. I did not say that they need be able to pass through a prescribed number of generic points.

Comment: @Ritwik There is no curve representing the class $L-E_1 -\cdots- E_8$ unless the 8 points are collinear.  That is the class of a line going through all eight points.

Comment: @Mark: I looked at the paper you sent (Cor 3.3 in particular). How is it answering my question? I am asking for a procedure to decide when is a class indecomposable. Cor 3.3 is talking about effective divisors.

Comment: @Mark and Artie: I just want to be sure I understand the paradox correctly. Let $\beta := 3L -E1-\ldots -E_8$. Assuming this is indecomposable, by Kontsevich and Mannin, $N_{\beta}$ is expected to be one. You think $N_{\beta}$ ought to be $12$. Why is that?

Comment: @Ritwik An effective divisor on a del Pezzo is just an algebraic curve in $X_k$ (but maybe of higher genus).  What Batyrev-Popov call "$M_{eff}(X_r)$" is the same thing as "$B$" in the Kontsevich-Manin paper, as far as I can tell.  They show that all these classes are sums of $(-1)$-curve classes, hence decomposable, with the possible exception of the anticanonical on the $8$ point blow-up.  But I have never thought about these sorts of questions, and it is entirely possible that I'm mistranslating something as I think about it!

Comment: @Ritwik An algebraic curve on $X_8$ representing $3L - \sum E_i$ is the strict transform of a cubic in $\mathbb P^2$ that goes through the $8$ points.  There is a 1-dimensional family of such cubics, but most of them are not parametrized by $\mathbb P^1$, and so don't contribute to $N_\beta$, as I understand it.  The ones that count for the $N_\beta$ are the cubics that are rational, of which there are 12 in a generic pencil of cubics (these are the 12 cubics with a node).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24172/discussion-between-ritwik-and-mark).

Comment: I can't get chat log-in to work.  I will try again later today.

Comment: Sure. Let me think about your observations in the meantime...Kontsveich and Mannin do say that the numbers are ``expected'' to be one...but I imagine they would have thought about this counter example to their expectation.

Comment: Sure, maybe it's a minor oversight.  But certainly Manin and Kontsevich both know more about curves on del Pezzos than I ever will, so more likely I misunderstand what $N_\beta$ is.

Answer (score 2):

Let me just summarize the comment thread in case someone more knowledgeable is willing to intervene.

Artie observes that [The Cox Ring of a Del Pezzo surface](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0309111) by Batyrev--Popov shows that every effective class on a del Pezzo with $k \geq 2$ is a sum of $(-1)$-curve classes, with one exception.  This means that no effective classes can be indecomposable in the sense above except for those of $(-1)$-curves.  All the $(-1)$-curve classes are clearly indecomposable and have $N_\delta = 1$.  And of course it is easy to write down these classes explicitly.

The one exception is that if $k = 8$ the anticanonical class is not a sum of two nonzero effective classes.  This class is represented by (the strict transforms of) the pencil of cubics through the 8 blown up points.  There are 12 singular cubics in the pencil, hence 12 that are rational, and it seems that we should have $N_\delta = 12$ by the OP's definition.  The catch is that Kontsevich-Manin "expect" $N_\delta = 1$ for an indecomposable class on a del Pezzo (page 29 of [the article](http://www.ihes.fr/~maxim/TEXTS/WithManinCohFT.pdf) in the question, following Claim 5.2.3).

So the question is, have we misunderstood something along the way (more likely, e.g. the definition of $N_\delta$), or did the authors forget a minor case?  (A secondary question: is this already worked out somewhere?)

Comment: I have asked this as a separate question. There is a further question I had about Kontsevich Mannis's paper. I combined that and your question in this thread http://mathoverflow.net/questions/207812/are-genus-zero-gromov-witten-invariants-on-del-pezzo-surfaces-enumerative